default.target is not inactive
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 but now my system doesn't start as I was used to.
I was trying to find information about how to launch as I want it and found to type this:
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/raw/main/system-info && \
chmod +x system-info && \
./system-info

Now I don't know, where the report  was sent to and how I may recieve the answere on how to make the system work again..
Hope to read from you!
Hannes

I could now get into system as used to.
My mistake was, that I was not following the instruction and did not type:
systemctl reboot
but:
exit, what has caused the default.target to close as well..
I am lucky for my mistake and that I could try to operate with Ubuntu without graphical interface, what might be the GUI..
